# Google share button, is it possible to share content from one URL and link back to another?

Tags: google-plus

Example an online learning application that you want to share your results which are behind a logged in part of your site. So you add a public URL to your site for google to fetch the content (img, description, title): 
data-href="http://www.example.com?result_id=24".

But then when someone views the post and sees the shared content and clicks the link to the site it goes to:

http://www.example.com?result_id=24

The only way I can think of is redirecting the user to http://www.example.com once they land on the shared URL.

Is there an official way or better way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, but there is a work around.

The URL that you share is used for both the snippet and place users are sent when they click.

However, you can put schema.org or OpenGraph markup on these pages that describes the content behind the login wall. This will allow you to specify a title, description and thumbnail. You can read more about configuring your snippet on [Google Developers](http://developers.google.com/+/plugins/snippet).

Comment: Thanks I did have a look at it. I checked out the schema.org reference and I specified <meta itemprop="url" content="http://www.example.com"> . When a post is shared and the title is clicked in google plus, the user will still get taken to http://www.example.com?result_id=24

Comment: Instead of using schema.org to specify a different URL, which will not work, make your login page aware of the intended target. Next, add schema.org markup for the title, description and image for the intended target to the login page. Does this make sense?